# Better way to crawl json

Tags: php, json

I have a function :

```
function personnesDispo($date){
  $mnsDispos = mnsDispos();
  for($j=0;$j<sizeof($mnsDispos);$j++){
    if($mnsDispos[$j]['date'] == $date){
      $mnsToday[$date][] = $mnsDispos[$j]['id'];
    }
  }
  $final = array_values(array_unique($mnsToday[$date]));
  return $final;
}
```

This function, crawls a json object. A big json object.
It takes so long for the function to crawl the json file, that I mostly have a 408 error..

Here is my json data : https://files.olivierlam.fr/json.txt

I can't find a better way for my function to be faster

My second function (I think it is this one that takes too long) :

```
function personneDispoToday($id,$date,$heure){
  $mnsDispos = mnsDispos();
  for($j=0;$j<sizeof($mnsDispos);$j++){
    if($mnsDispos[$j]['date'] == $date AND $mnsDispos[$j]['heure'] == $heure AND $mnsDispos[$j]['id'] == $id){
      $dispo = [
        'id' => $mnsDispos[$j]['id'],
        'dispo' => $mnsDispos[$j]['dispo']
      ];
      return $dispo;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

This function, is used to display 1 or 2. But is almost similar to the first function. 
I think that, combining the two function in one might help

Comment: Thats not JSON? If you show us the real json or a `var_export()` of the object/array then we can test our answers

Comment: Thats not json, thats a var_dump of an array. You have to `print json_encode($yourArray);` instead of `var_dump($yourArray);`

Comment: I have updated the file

Comment: https://files.olivierlam.fr/json.txt

Comment: What does `mnsDispos()` do?

Comment: it displays https://files.olivierlam.fr/json.txt this json

Comment: By the way how is this JSON generated? Is it coming from a database?

Comment: @RaymondNijland it is, from the function mnsDispos()

Comment: Then you should do the filtering in your database and not in PHP on JSON data..  I advice to show your complete PHP code how the JSON is generated and the SQL tables and example data and expected result see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for proving example data and expected results.

Comment: *"What does mnsDispos() do?"* @RiggsFolly seams it fetches and generates JSON from a database table(s)..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yea, far to little actual information in this question as it turns out. :)

Comment: @RaymondNijland I’ll read that thanks

Comment: One obvious suggestion would be to run `mnsDispos()` ONCE outside all these functions and do as I did and pass the array of objects around to each function that needs it

Answer (score 2):

I dont see why your code is taking so long, but maybe there is processing you are not showing us.

This code takes quite a bit less than a second to decode the JSON String and loop through the complete sample JSON and capture the new array of data for the date passed as a paramter

```
function personnesDispo(&$j_array, $date){
    $today = [];
    foreach($j_array as $obj) {
        if ( $obj->date == $date ){
            $today[$date][] = $obj;
        }
        $c++;
    }
    return $today;
}

$startTime = microtime(true);

$j_array = json_decode($s); // $s was your sample JSON String

$result = personnesDispo($j_array, '25-05-2019');
print_r($result);

$endTime = microtime(true);
$execution_time = ($endTime - $startTime)/60;
echo '<b>Total Execution Time:</b> '.$execution_time.' Mins'.PHP_EOL;
echo 'Array objects of size = ' . count($j_array);
```

The result is

```
Array
(
    [25-05-2019] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [prenom] => Guillaume
                    [nom] => HUART
                    [date] => 25-05-2019
                    [heure] => 06:00:00
                    [dispo] => 1
                    [id] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [prenom] => Guillaume
                    [nom] => HUART
                    [date] => 25-05-2019
                    [heure] => 07:00:00
                    [dispo] => 1
                    [id] => 1
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [prenom] => Guillaume
                    [nom] => HUART
                    [date] => 25-05-2019
                    [heure] => 08:00:00
                    [dispo] => 1
                    [id] => 1
                )

    ... lots more

           [111] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [prenom] => Charly
                    [nom] => PLAIGNAUD
                    [date] => 25-05-2019
                    [heure] => 23:00:00
                    [dispo] => 1
                    [id] => 51
                )

            [112] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [prenom] => Charly
                    [nom] => PLAIGNAUD
                    [date] => 25-05-2019
                    [heure] => 24:00:00
                    [dispo] => 1
                    [id] => 51
                )

        )

)
<b>Total Execution Time:</b> 0.00014141400655111 Mins
Array objects of size = 2244
```

> Even using a slightly rewritten version of the second function, when the JSON data is passed around as a parameter to each function instead of rebuilt inside each function the timing does not change much

```
function personnesDispo(&$j_array, $date){
    $today = [];
    foreach($j_array as $a) {

        if ( $a->date == $date ){
            $today[$date][] = $a;
        }
    }
    return $today;
}

function personneDispoToday(&$j_array,$id,$date,$heure){
    foreach($j_array as $a) {
        if($a->date == $date AND $a->heure == $heure AND $a->id == $id){
              $dispo = [
                'id' => $a->id,
                'dispo' => $a->dispo
              ];
              return $dispo;
              break;
        }
    }
}

$startTime = microtime(true);

$j_array = json_decode($s);

$result = personnesDispo($j_array, '25-05-2019');
print_r($result);

$result2 = personneDispoToday($j_array,51,'25-05-2019','24:00:00');
print_r($result2);


$endTime = microtime(true);
echo "Start Time $startTime" . PHP_EOL;
echo "End Time $endTime" . PHP_EOL;

$execution_time = ($endTime - $startTime)/60;

echo "Execution Time $execution_time" . PHP_EOL;

echo '<b>Total Execution Time:</b> '.$execution_time.' Mins'.PHP_EOL;
echo 'Array objects of size = ' . count($j_array);
```

RESULTS

```
Same big array as before plus

Array
(
    [id] => 51
    [dispo] => 1
)
Start Time 1556899734.5787
End Time 1556899734.5871
Execution Time 0.00014118353525798
<b>Total Execution Time:</b> 0.00014118353525798 Mins
Array objects of size = 2244
```

Comment: You are right, there is another function I forgot to mention. I have edited the post

Comment: Like you said in the upper comment, I passed the mnsDispos() as an array parameter and so I decided to optimize another function. And it works better ! It's much faster, thanks !